# Little endian or Big endian

Tags: c, math, arithmetic-expressions

```
#include <stdio.h>

union Endian
{
    int i;
    char c[sizeof(int)];
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    union Endian e;
    e.i = 1;
    printf("%d \n",&e.i);
    printf("%d,%d,\n",e.c[0],&(e.c[0]));
    printf("%d,%d",e.c[sizeof(int)-1],&(e.c[sizeof(int)-1]));


}
```

OUTPUT:

```
1567599464 
1,1567599464,
0,1567599467
```

LSB is stored in the lower address and MSB is stored in the higher address. Isn't this supposed to be big endian? But my system config shows it as a little endian architecture.

Comment: "Little endian": little end first; "Big endian": big end first

Comment: @tez In `little-endian` lSB is stored in lower address.Lower address,in crude terms, is the address beginning with the left.And LSB, in crude terms, is the rightmost byte in a mathematical binary representation.So the rightmost byte is stored in the leftmost address in `little-endian`.No wonder your architecture is `little-endian`

Comment: @tez Whenever you are printing addresses,it is proper to cast them to `void*` and use the `%p` format specifier.`%d` is a pure no-no as it is for signed-integers.Addresses are never signed.

Comment: and not to mention UB:-) .

Comment: How do you expect e.c[0] to have value one without you ever initializing the c char array. This could be garbage value. isn't it?

Comment: @shazin In unions, you initialize one union element at one time.

Comment: @shazin When OP used `e.i=1`,e.c[0] gets its value too as they have the same address.That's what unions is all about,in contrast to structures.

Comment: @Rüppell'sVulture , shazin its undefined behaviour to do that. writing to one and reading from the other is not well formed in unions

Comment: @Rüppell'sVulture Thanks for pointing out %p but why to cast it to a void pointer?

Comment: @tez because `%p` expects that,just like %d expects an integer ,not a float

Comment: @shazin 'int i' will take care of that

Comment: @tez It should be `printf("%d,%p,\n",e.c[0],(void*)&(e.c[0]));`

Comment: @Rüppell'sVulture Thankyou.But won't it be casted implicitly??

Comment: @tez It's better to follow the rules.You may get the same result some times if you use `%u` in place of `%p, but that's not always assured.So it's better to stick to rules.

Comment: @pmg That doesn't make any sense, a number only has one ending! :) (The ending, I suppose, would be the LS number.) But there's no rational meaning of the terms little & big endian, their names are merely taken from a famous book by Jonathan Swift where two nations fought a fierce war about whether a boiled egg should first be opened at the narrow or wide side. As in: there is no obvious advantage of either form, nor any right or wrong.

Comment: @Lundin: what I meant was, for example for the number `73.5`, the big end is the `7`; the little end is the `5` (in decimal representation)

Comment: @Koushik It's not UB per se to read from a different union member than the one last stored in C (in C++, it is). You may get a trap representation, and if the read member is larger than the stored, the bytes not corresponding to the stored member have indeterminate value. Neither applies here, so the behaviour is not undefined (but unspecified, since it depends on endianness).

Comment: @DanielFischer yet another difference i learnt between c and c++. so subtle. thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You system is definitely `little-endian`. Had it been `big-endian`, the following code:

```
printf("%d,%d,\n",e.c[0],&(e.c[0]));
```

would print `0` for the first `%d` instead of `1`. In `little-endian` 1 is stored as

```
00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000
^ LSB
^Lower Address
```

but in `big-endian` it is stored as

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001
                           ^LSB
                           ^Higher Address
```

And don't use the `%d` to print addresses of variables, use `%p`.

Comment: One more Question.In a char array, does c[0] will always be at lower address when compared to c[1], regardless of system and compiler??

Comment: @tez Yes & No!! Generally we can expect the array elements to be stored in consecutive memory locations starting with the lower address to higher address (The addresses are **always** consecutive,else pointer arithmetic won't work on the array).But there are cases like when the `stack grows backwards`.I can't explain that in rigorous words,so you should put it in another question so that top contributors like Jonathan Leffer,David Pischer or Mat can answer.

Comment: @tez I've posted that question for you.Here's the link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16397175/are-the-elements-of-an-array-guaranteed-to-be-stored-from-lower-to-higher-addres/16397227?noredirect=1#16397227

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. Hope one day I'll have enough knowledge to contribute to this wonderful community.

Answer (score 2):

For little endian, the least significant bits are stored in the first byte (with the lowest address).

That's what you're seeing, so it seems there is sanity ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
00000001 (Hexadecimal: 32 bits)
^^    ^^
MS    LS
Byte  Byte
```

Least Significant Byte at lowest address => **little-endian**. The integer is placed into memory, **starting** from its little-end. Hence the name.

[**Endianness**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)

Comment: I am afraid you are wrong.You are talking about **bits** in you illustration,and you are using terms like MSB and LSB which are related to **Bytes** not **Bits**.

Comment: Order of bits in a byte don't differ between `little-endian` and `big-endian`.The above illustration is completely wrong.

Comment: @Rüppell'sVulture I point to a set of **2** nibbles, in hex. I was referring to bytes, not bits. Edited to make it clearer.

Comment: @Rüppell'sVulture : I think that might have been a hexadecimal value, rather than a binary value - it's admittedly hard to distinguish.

Answer (score 1):

You have the byte containing "1" (least significant) as first element (e.c[0]) and the byte containing "0" being the second one (e.c[1]). This is litte endian, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

You are wrong about what is Big endian and what is little endian. Read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)

Answer (score 0):

Looks good to me. "little endian" (aka "the right way" :-) means "lower-order bytes stored first", and that's exactly what your code shows. (BTW, you should use "%p" to print the addresses).

Comment: -1 for calling the right way to little endian! Saying the temperature is 5 tenths, and 3 units and 7 tens is not the right way :)

Comment: I come from a C background. Seems to me that `(short)i` ought to equal `*(short *)(&i)`.